# Method 'get_HistoryInfos' does not have an implementation

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'get_HistoryInfos' in type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper' from assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' does not have an implementation.'

Running into issues with my Visual Studio 2019 project, which is using CrystalReports Service Pack 30. When attempting to create a ReportDocument object, the system throws an error (see text above). Attempted for several days to find a solution online, and am not sure what to do next to rectify the problem. Any feedback or assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I installed crystal report for Visual Studio 2019. after installation when I run my web application, this error is displaying on my screen. I tried different solutions like I change versions of Crystal report and also change the configuration of Crystal report in web.config file, but still this error is on my screen.